# Why isn't acceleration always zero whenever velocity is zero, such as the moment a ball bounces off a wall?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, velocity, collision

The answer to this homework problem is $\left(\text{D}\right) :$

> [image]

I understand why we rule out options $\left(\text{A}\right)$ and $\left(\text{B}\right)$ first. However, I don't get why $\left(\text{D}\right)$ is the answer.

Won't the ball's velocity at one point be $0$ when it comes in contact with the ceiling? (The same way as its velocity momentarily is $0$ when it is thrown downwards and comes in contact with the ground before bouncing back upwards). That should give zero acceleration at that point, but none of the acceleration profiles include $0 .$

Comment: Yes, the velocity will be zero momentarily. Why would that mean the acceleration is zero?

Comment: a=v-u/t? From this, acceleration should be zero when velocity is zero.

Comment: Acceleration is the rate of change of velocity, $a = \Delta v/\Delta t$. The rate of change of $v$ can be non-zero even when $v=0$. Think about the simpler case of a ball thrown in the air. At the top of its motion, momentarily $v=0$, but there is still acceleration due to gravity, which is why the ball starts moving back down.

Comment: @ClarkKent By your argument the ball could never be thrown: It starts in-hand with zero velocity and thus cannot be accelerated.

Comment: The derivative of the zero *function* is zero, not the derivative of a function whenever it is zero.

Comment: It may help to think about velocity vs. acceleration by analogy to position vs. velocity; these have very similar relationships to each other, and somehow human brains are wired to understand the latter two much more intuitively. So: a car is driving uptown, hitting green lights at every intersection and passing side streets at 20mph. In this city, they've numbered the side streets; it's in the south but heading north. Eventually it will pass 1st Street South, then 0th Street, then 1st Street North. At the moment that its position reaches 0th street, does its velocity drop to 0mph, too?

Comment: It's certainly not accelerating _upwards_ at that point. But, then again, it never was.

Comment: Drawing graphs of the ball's position and velocity might help.

Comment: @HABO Not necessarily, consider $x(t)=t^3$ which has acceleration zero when the velocity is zero.

Comment: Something that might help you identify where your thinking collides with what happens in the world around you: think about watching this experiment from an elevator moving upwards at constant velocity. When would you expect acceleration to be zero in that setting?

Answer (score 13):

You could consider the question in terms of the forces acting on the ball.

During the entire time a downward force of gravity acts on it.  While it is in contact with the ceiling there is also a downwards normal force.  At no time are there balanced forces acting on the ball

This results in an acceleration is always downwards with a spike in magnitude while the ball is in contact with the ceiling.

Answer (score 8):

> Won't the ball's velocity at one point be 0 when it comes in contact with the ceiling? (The same way as its velocity momentarily is 0 when it is thrown downwards and comes in contact with the ground before bouncing back upwards).

Yes. Its velocity will momentarily be zero.

> That should give zero acceleration at that point[...]

No! *Velocity* being zero says nothing about the *acceleration*. Just like your *position* being zero (i.e. when returning home after a day at work) says nothing about your *velocity* (you could be running in high speed when arriving at your starting position, or you could reach it slowly, or you could stand still at the starting spot. Different velocities are possible where the position is zero; position and velocity are unrelated, and so are velocity and acceleration).

When throwing a ball up, the ball will also momentarily reach zero speed before falling back down to your hand. But gravity is there all the time causing a non-zero acceleration all the time - also when the speed is zero. So, **acceleration can't be understood from the value of velocity, only from the *change* in the value of velocity.**

And why the peak then in answer D? Because,

- while flying upwards, gravity causes a constant downwards acceleration. The ball slows down at a constant rate.
- When hitting the ceiling, the ceiling suddenly slows down the ball instantly. That requires a much larger downwards acceleration in that instant in order to reduce the speed to zero in very short time. Thus the peak on the graph.

Answer (score 3):

It is often supposed that because a quantity (velocity in this case) is zero the rate of change of that quantity (acceleration in this case) is also zero.
If that were true a ball which is thrown upwards would stay at its greatest height above the ground when it was not moving and never come back to the ground.

Just suppose that you were correct and at the instant the velocity of the ball was zero the acceleration $( = \frac{\text{change in velocity}}{\text{time}})$ was also zero.

This means that at some instant if time the velocity of the ball does not change from being zero ie the ball is not moving and will stay in a position of rest on the ceiling for all time.

Comment: Okay, I now understand why acceleration isnt zero. Can you explain why D is the answer?

Comment: @ClarkKent Up is positive and the acceleration of free fall is downwards ie negative.  When the ball hits the ceiling a downward force due to the ceiling acts on the ball increasing the ball’s downward acceleration.